# How to access resources of installed module from another module?

Tags: node.js

I've a node application which uses source of certain js libs as a raw source (to inject it in a certain place remotely).

Those js libs where manually extracted from node_modules and are directly loaded in application via fs.

How can those files be loaded from node modules instead of loading them directly?

The main problem is that those modules can be globally installed, so i can't just hardcode path node_modules/required_module/required_file.js.

Comment: Why wouldn't you package the source you want into an actual module and place the actual module in an expected location for a module (either locally or globally) and then just use `require()` to load the module?  Why are you trying to avoid using the module loading system?'

Comment: @jfriend00 i need source javascript, not javascript object. Source is needed to be passed to remote js vm.

Comment: Your question is just not clear at all what you're trying to do.  What does "Passed to remote js. vm." even mean?  You've now gone 13 hours without a meaningful answer and that's likely because nobody understands what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially test various global paths to see if you can find the file.  Usually global modules are installed in the same location on most machines.  However, this isn't a very good solution.  You'll run into issues with users who use NVM.

Your best bet is to just copy the file into your own source.

Comment: Thanx for answer, also i've found i can just replicate `require` module search pattern.